# if AD ≥ BC, BC ≥ AD then BC = AD

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I thought it could be solved this way:

(i)$ad-bc \geq 0$ and $bc-ad \geq 0$

Therefore, when adding it, we are left with the inequality

$(ad - bc) + (bc-ad) \geq 0$

when ordering, we are left with $0$, therefore $0=0$

This proves that 0=0, which we already knew, but it does not show that $BC=AD$.

*I thought to use antisymmetric but I don't know how it would look*

Comment: Is the squeeze theorem valid here? If so then the answer is obvious.

Comment: $BC$ can't be greater or smaller than $AD$. Therefore both are equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Real Analysis, given $r,s \in \Bbb{R},$ either $r < s, r= s,$ or $r > s.$

Further, $r > s \iff (r - s) > 0$

and $r \geq s \iff (r - s) \geq 0.$

So, you have that $r - s \geq 0.$

Suppose that $s - r > 0.$

Then, you would have that $0 = (r - s) + (s - r) > 0.$  This is a contradiction.

Therefore, it is not the case that $s - r > 0.$

However, you know that $s - r \geq 0.$  Therefore, you can conclude that $s - r = 0 \implies s = r.$

---

The problem can be attacked a different way.

Since $r \geq s$, it is not the case that $r < s.$

Since $s \geq r,$ and it is not the case that $s > r$, it must be the case that $s = r.$

Answer (score 0):

You are actually very close. Because the sum of your two inequalities $ad\geq bc$ and $bc\geq ad$ gives you an equality, you know that both of the original inequalities must achieve equality (because if one or both of them didn't, the left side would always be greater). Therefore ad=bc.