# get equality from 2 inequalities

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

given two inequalities:

1. $A \leq D$
2. $D \leq A$

is it right to say that D and A are close to each other, and $A\approx D$

i dont know if i can see that $A = D$, but maybe $A\approx D$, is it true

Comment: It seems to me that if you define the relation $\geq $ as being a partial order, then yes, if $A \geq B$ and $ B \geq A$, then $A = B$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [if AD ≥ BC, BC ≥ AD then BC = AD](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4588125/if-ad-%e2%89%a5-bc-bc-%e2%89%a5-ad-then-bc-ad)

Comment: Note that this holds for any partial order $\sim$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A=D+c$, where $c$ is some real number. Since $A\le D$, we have $A\le A+c.$ Subtracting $A$ on both sides leads to $0\le c$, so $c$ is non-negative. Moreover, since $D\le A$, we have $A+c\le A$, so subtract $A$ on both sides to obtain $c\le 0$. Therefore, $c$ is also non-positive. Since $c$ is not negative or positive, it must be zero. We conclude $$A=D+c=D+0=D.$$